# InfluxDB - How can I get a maximum value in the point?

Tags: influxdb

fellows.

I'm new to InfluxDB and I'd like to get a maximum value in the point.
I think it must be very simple, but, since InfluxDB's MAX() function does not take muliple fields, I don't know how to get a result I want.

My measurement looks like this:

```
{
    time: <timestamp>,
    tags: {
        station: <station-code>,
    },
    fields: {
        e-componet: <value>,
        n-componet: <value>,
        z-componet: <value>,
    }
}
```

Let's say these are my data:

```
time                  station   e-componet  n-componet  z-componet
------------------------------------------------------------
2019-08-14T00:20:00Z  A        -10         10.9        -11.8
2019-08-14T00:10:00Z  A        -9.9        10.8        -10.8
2019-08-14T00:00:00Z  A        -9.8        10.7        -10.8
2019-08-13T23:50:00Z  A        -9.8        10.7        -10.8
2019-08-13T23:40:00Z  A        -9.7        10.6        -10.4
2019-08-13T23:30:00Z  A        -9.7        10.5        -10.4
2019-08-13T23:20:00Z  A        -9.5        10.5        -10.3
2019-08-13T23:10:00Z  A        -9.4        10.4        -10.3
```

And I'd like to get a result like this:

```
time                  station   MAX(ABS(e-componet), ABS(n-componet), ABS(z-componet))
-------------------------------------------
2019-08-14T00:20:00Z  A         11.8
2019-08-14T00:10:00Z  A         10.8
2019-08-14T00:00:00Z  A         10.8
2019-08-13T23:50:00Z  A         10.8
2019-08-13T23:40:00Z  A         10.6
2019-08-13T23:30:00Z  A         10.5
2019-08-13T23:20:00Z  A         10.5
2019-08-13T23:10:00Z  A         10.4
```

I've tried several queries, but, I couldn't get a desired result.
Any comments will be welcome.

Comment: Mind sharing any of those queries you tried ?
It may be helpful for others to see what doesn't work.
Also it may help people point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT max("$FIELD_NAME") FROM "$DB" WHERE time >= now() - 6h GROUP BY "$TAG"
```

Above query was copied from grafana. You could use grafana for better monitoring.

[Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/mssql/)

Comment: That is certainly a nice query but it does not help in solving the OP's question ...